# URL Key for product doesn't accept hyphens

Tags: product, url-rewrite, validation, form-validation

When editing a product I migrated over from a woocommerce store and NOT changing the URL Key I get the following error. Hyphens are a must in URL Keys, what can I do

[image: URL Key only accepts letters [a-zA-Z] and numbers [0-9]]

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Disabling the translation did little good.

These are the extensions we have enabled:

- Cm_RedisSession
- Interface_Adminhtml_Default
- Interface_Frontend_Base_Default
- Interface_Frontend_Default
- Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default
- Interface_Install_Default
- Lib_Cm
- Lib_Credis
- Lib_Google_Checkout
- Lib_Js_Calendar
- Lib_Js_Ext
- Lib_Js_Mage
- Lib_Js_Prototype
- Lib_Js_TinyMCE
- Lib_LinLibertineFont
- Lib_Mage
- Lib_Magento
- Lib_Phpseclib
- Lib_Varien
- Lib_ZF
- Lib_ZF_Locale
- Mage_All_Latest
- Mage_Centinel
- Mage_Compiler
- Mage_Core_Adminhtml
- Mage_Core_Modules
- Mage_Downloader
- Mage_Locale_de_DE
- Mage_Locale_en_US
- Mage_Locale_es_ES
- Mage_Locale_fr_FR
- Mage_Locale_nl_NL
- Mage_Locale_pt_BR
- Mage_Locale_zh_CN
- Magento_Mobile
- Phoenix_Moneybookers
- MTurbo
- Fooman_Speedster
- AW_Blog
- magento_community_Ebcomm_PaypalMx
- Olark_Chatbox

Comment: What version of Magento are you running? Magento, by default, will accept hyphens (-). I just confirmed as well on my clean copy. Do you have any custom extensions that interfere with the product controller? I can tell that you are using a translation extension as well, if you disable this, does the issue go away?

Comment: The version is 1.9.0.1 and indeed Magento will allow hyphens in other installs. The translation didn't make a difference once disabled. I will add all extensions in original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that modifying the URL Key attribute (Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attribute) and changing the input validation did the trick, it would be nice to have validation that checked for url compatible inputs.

[image: Change Input Validation for Store Owner]